# Filter list with two criteria and create a map scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, mapreduce

I have a case class which keeps transactions(assume as fund transfers). For the sake of simplicity I will use below one

```
case class Trans(from: String, to: String, amount: Int)
```

I have list of transactions

```
val tl = List(
  Trans("a", "b", 30), 
  Trans("a", "c", 40),
  Trans("b", "c", 10),
  Trans("b", "a", 25),
  Trans("c", "a", 15)
)
```

I want to group this list based on **from** and **to**. Then needs to take the sum of the groups to a **Map**. Map keeps elements in below structure

```
("a" -> (70, 40))
// "a" is the key
// "70" is the sum of values where "a" is 'from' (30 + 40)
// "40" is the sum of values where "a" is 'to' (25 + 15)
```

For an instance the about list should populate output as

```
Map("a" -> (70, 40), "b" -> (35, 30), "c" -> (15, 50))
```

I can do this filtering with two statements and combine them like below

```
// out map
val mOut = tl.map(t => (t.from, t.amount)).groupBy(_._1).map(s => (s._1, s._2.sum))

// in map
val mIn = tl.map(t => (t.to, t.amount)).groupBy(_._1).map(s => (s._1, s._2.sum))

// finally I can join these tow maps to have the final output
```

Are there any way to do it with single/one statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're `cats` or `scalaz` user, you can use `foldMap`:

```
import cats._, implicits._ // or...
//import scalaz._, Scalaz._


case class Trans(from: String, to: String, amount: Int)

val tl = List(
  Trans("a", "b", 30), 
  Trans("a", "c", 40),
  Trans("b", "c", 10),
  Trans("b", "a", 25),
  Trans("c", "a", 15)
)

tl foldMap {
    case Trans(from, to, am) => Map(from -> (am, 0), to -> (0, am))
}
```

Comment: Are there any way to to extract case class object list instead of Map via scalaz function. For an instance, If I have `case class Bal(name: String, in: Int, out: Int)` can I extract list of these case class objects `List(Bal("a", 70, 40), Bal("b", 35, 30), Bal("c", 15, 50))`

Comment: In above example with foldMap it will returns a `Map("a" -> (70, 40), "b" -> (35, 30), "c" -> (15, 50))` instead of Map I want to return a list of case class objects like `List(Bal("a", 70, 40), Bal("b", 35, 30), Bal("c", 15, 50))`. In here `Bal` is a case class. `case class Bal(name: String, in: Int, out: Int)`

Comment: @eranga no, you have to follow up with another map for that `foldMap(...).map { case (name, (in, out)) => Bal(name, in, out) }). `foldMap` uses `Monoid` which has specific meaning for each class & its own rules

Comment: It's done  
`val m = tl.foldMap {
    case Trans(from, to, am) =>
      Map(from -> (am, 0), to -> (0, am))
  }.map {
    case (name, (in, out)) =>
      Bal(name, in, out)
  }`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need scalaz for this. .
I think, what you are looking for is `flatMap`:

```
   tl
    .flatMap { p => 
       p.from -> (p.amount, 0),
       p.to -> (0, p.amount)
    }.groupBy(_._1)
     .mapValues { tuples => 
        tuples.foldLeft((0,0)) { case ((a,b), (_, (c,d))) => (a+c, b+d) } 
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work in a single traversal of the list.

```
tl.foldLeft(Map.empty[String,(Int,Int)].withDefaultValue((0,0))){
  case (m,Trans(from,to,amount)) =>
    val (fromA, fromB) = m(from)
    val (toA, toB) = m(to)
    m + (from -> (fromA+amount, fromB)) + (to -> (toA, toB+amount))
}
//res0: Map[String,(Int, Int)] = Map(a -> (70,40), b -> (35,30), c -> (15,50))
```

Hopefully you can come up with better names for the intermediate variables.